# Ubuntu detects half of external disk

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, disk-space, fdisk

I have a Virtual Machine that has 3 disks.
The third one is 150Go size, I get this with `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc`:

```
/dev/sdc1            2048   314572799   157285376   83  Linux
```

However, `df` command returns only half of this disk:

```
/dev/sdc1       78609980 71274061   7335919  91% /mnt/data
```

How is that possible?

**Update**

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc`

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 161.1 GB, 161061273600 bytes 3 têtes, 8 secteurs/piste, 
13107200 cylindres, total 314572800 secteurs Unités = secteurs de 1 * 512 = 
512 octets Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets 
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets Identifiant de 
disque : 0x557ee3ef

Périphérique Amorce  Début        Fin      Blocs     Id  Système 
/dev/sdc1             2048   314572799   157285376   83  Linux
```

`df -k  /dev/sdc1` returns this:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1       78609980 71279103   7330877  91% /mnt/data
```

`df -h  /dev/sdc1` gets this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1        75G   68G  7.0G  91% /mnt/data
```

`POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 df /dev/sdc1` gets this:

```
Filesystem     512B-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1        157219960 142558210  14661750  91% /mnt/data
```

**Update 2**

`lsblk` gets this:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
sda      8:0    0    12G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  11,5G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0   487M  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0    30G  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0    30G  0 part
sdc      8:32   0   150G  0 disk
└─sdc1   8:33   0   150G  0 part /mnt/data
```

**Updtae 3**

I got this running `tune2fs -l`:

```
Inode count:              104857600
Block count:              104857600
Reserved block count:     0
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't really understand what you mean.
Here is the content of `/etc/fstab`:
`/dev/sdc1  /mnt/data       ext4  user,noatime               0       2`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I updated the question

Comment: What is `Block size` in the output of `tune2fs -l`?

Comment: `Block size:               1024`

Comment: According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/622523/693277) your filesystem as a whole takes exactly 100 GiB. It doesn't take the whole partition then. Why `df` reports so little total size, this I don't know (yet).

Answer (score 1):

The partition is indeed about 150 GiB in size and it takes practically the whole device.

In `fdisk` the columns `Start` and `End` (`Début` and `Fin` in your case) are measured in sectors. A sector is 512 bytes in your case. The column `Blocks` however uses 1 KiB unit, quite confusing. If it said `Sectors` instead, the unit would be 512 B as well. I believe newer versions of `fdisk` use sectors. Compare [this old question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120734/108618).

---

<sub>Note: I know from your comment the filesystem is ext4.</sub>

---

#### Maybe...

Maybe your filesystem is not as big as the partition. Somebody has created it smaller; or the partition used to be smaller and it got expanded without expanding the filesystem later.

A filesystem smaller than its partition is possible (yet rather uncommon). See `man mkfs.ext4`, `fs-size` parameter.

Now you have two options to reclaim the missing part of your disk space:

- Investigate how big exactly the filesystem is; shrink the partition (not too much!); create additional partition(s) and filesystem(s).
- Enlarge the filesystem with `resize2fs`. Make sure your Ubuntu can do this (12.04 is quite old, it's beyond my expertise to tell whether or not it's relevant).

The second option seems safer and less error-prone. I think `resize2fs` can detect the size of the partition and enlarge your filesystem to the maximum, so you don't have to calculate anything. Read the manual before you proceed.

---

#### Or maybe...

Or maybe the filesystem is as big as the partition but it reserves about 50% of its size for root. Use `tune2fs -l` to investigate. Compare `Reserved block count` to `Block count`. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/445605/432690).

You can change the reserved percentage with `tune2fs -m` or `tune2fs -r`. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/176133/432690).

Comment: I updated the question. Reserved block count = 0 !